# How to revive VirtualBox sound efficiently?

Tags: virtualbox, audio

When plugging and unplugging a USB headset on my Win7 host, sound from my Ubuntu18 VM hangs (both GUI sounds and `paplay` on the cmdline do hang).
Disabling and re-enabling sound for the VM does not help (continues to hang). VirtualBox is Version 6.0.22.
Problem seems to be triggered by a change of the default host sound device, as Windows forcefully makes a new sound device the default sound device which then disappears when unplugging it.

As a workaround, I'm quitting the VM, saving the machine state and then starting the saved VM again: At this time, sound is revived and continues to play from before the hang without further actions on the VM itself, but this is very inefficient.

Is there some more efficient way to revive VirtualBox VM sound after a host sound config change ?
Or is it even possible to prevent the sound from hanging at all ?

Comment: Have you tried upgrading VirtualBox to the latest version?

Comment: @gronostaj No, but if somebody says this will fix the issue I would upgrade. This problem has been present in previous VirtualBox versions, too, so I don't expect it to be already fixed.